# Multiplication proof by induction

Tags: analysis, induction

Prove by induction that $$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}  r = \frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$$

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

This is straight forward. But how can it be used to show the following:

$$\Pi_{r=0}^{n-1} e^\frac{2ri\pi}{n}=(-1)^{n-1}$$

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! This formula is false.

Comment: Apologies, edited.

Comment: @coreyman317 Apologies, just edited.

Comment: Notice that the second expression may be rewritten as $e^{\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}(\frac{2ri\pi}{n})}=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}r}=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n}*(\frac{n(n-1)}{2})}=(e^{\pi i})^{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 But note that the second expression involves multiplicative notation rather than summation notation.

Comment: @BernardKeynes Note that $e^a*e^b=e^{a+b}$

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 If you could explain how exactly the multiplication notation disappears?

Comment: If you accept that $e^a*e^b=e^{a+b}$, we can easily show by induction that $e^{a_1}*e^{a_2}*...*e^{a_n}=e^{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}$ so $e^{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{2ri\pi}{n}}=e^{\frac{0}{n}}*e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n}}*...e^{{2(n-1)i\pi}{n}}=e^{\frac{0}{n}+\frac{2i\pi}{n}+...+\frac{2i(n-1)\pi}{n}}=e^{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{2ir\pi}{n}}$

Comment: Did you try summing the exponents of the factors $e^{\frac {2ri\pi}{n}}$ in your product?  Then apply your summation formula.

Answer (score 0):

$\prod{e^\frac{2i\pi r}{n}}= \exp( \frac{2i \pi \sum{r}}{n}) = \exp ( \frac{ 2i \pi n (n -1)}{2n}) = (e^{i \pi})^{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}$